# Get network protocol of a mounted volume using Python

Tags: python, macos

We were using AFP (Apple File Protocol) to connect volumes on a NAS to our macOS clients.
As Apple is phasing out AFP, we (mostly) switched to SMB.

Now I have to clean up filenames that do not work any longer on SMB. E.g. "name " with a space at the end works fine on AFP, but is made into something random like "NBFRO", on SMB.

I made a Python script that finds these issues and corrects them. It has to run on the volume mounted via AFP. The volumes usually are already mounted. Instead of relying on myself not to forget, to mount the volumes the correct way, I would like the script to check if the volume is mounted with the correct protocol (AFP).

**Is there a way in Python (3.x), to find the used protocol for an volume already mounted?**

I checked `pathlib` and `os.path`, but couldn’t find anything helpful.

Comment: You could check `psutil`

Comment: Thanks! I checked the documentation. There are sections on ›DIsk‹ and ›Network‹, but it seems these functions are too low level. I couldn’t find anything that looks like it could be of use for my issue.

Comment: I think you can find it using `psutil.disk_partitions` https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=disk_partitions#psutil.disk_partitions

Comment: I’ve seen this and didn’t think it would help. 
Actually it returns the protocol in the ``fstype``-key:

AFP is named `afpfs`, while SMB is `smbfs`. And external volumes are only listed with parameter `all=True`.

Thanks!

Comment: Does `diskutil list` give the information you need ?

Comment: I’m not 100% sure, but it seems like `diskutil` doesn’t list network volumes. This would make sense, as it is meant to manipulate the structure of the disk. Anyway, the solution with `psutil` works fine. Maybe I wasn’t clear enough about this in my previous comment. I would have marked @executable’s comment as correct, but I think this is only possible with answers.

Comment: Does `psutil.disk_partitions` list network volumes ?

Comment: @Philippe yes, but only with the parameter `all=True` (default is `False`)